# how to write junit for this method

Tags: junit

how can i write junit for my  AddressBO  class ?
if 2 address are same return RED....

```
public class AddressBO {
    public String checkAddresses(String address1, String address2) {
        if(address1.equals(address2))
            return "RED";
        else if(address1.equalsIgnoreCase(address2))
            return "BLUE";
        else if(address1.replaceAll("\\s", "").equals(address2.replaceAll("\\s", "")))
            return "YELLOW";
        return "GREEN";
    }
}
```

And test class is ...........................

```
@Test
    public void testCheckAddressesRed() {
        //fill the code
    }

    public void testCheckAddressesBlue() {
        //fill the code
    }
    public void testCheckAddressesYellow() {
        //fill the code
    }
    public void testCheckAddressesGreen() {
        //fill the code
    }
```

Comment: This is a bad test , you test the behaviour of class with conditions , you don't write tests for results. In your case you should create 3 condition like

testCheckAddressesWhenAddress1EqualsAddress2

testCheckAddressesWhenAddress1EqualsIgnoreCaseAddress2

testCheckAddressesWhenAddress1TrimEqualsAddress2Trim

Answer (score 0):

It works

```
public class AddressJUnit {
        @Before
        public void createBoInstance() {
           AddressBO ad=new AddressBO();
        }
        @Test
        public void testCheckAddressesRed() {
            AddressBO ad=new AddressBO();
             assertEquals("RED", ad.checkAddresses("pune", "pune"));
        }
        @Test
        public void testCheckAddressesBlue() {
            AddressBO ad=new AddressBO();
             assertEquals("BLUE", ad.checkAddresses("pUne", "pune"));
             }
        @Test
        public void testCheckAddressesYellow() {
            AddressBO ad=new AddressBO();
             assertEquals("YELLOW", ad.checkAddresses("pu ne", "pune"));
        }
        @Test
        public void testCheckAddressesGreen() {
             AddressBO ad=new AddressBO();
             assertEquals("GREEN", ad.checkAddresses("pu", "pune"));
        }
```